# Delete functionality is not working properly-Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

i have created delete functionality,in which when user clicks delete[X] it has to get deleted from the respected row w.r.t datagrid view used in react

passing id as an parameter
used _find index(loadlash)

problem:

1) selected Rows are not getting deleted.

code:

onclick event

```
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.deleteHandler(params.value)}>X</button>
      </div>
```

Delete code:

```
 deleteHandler = (id) => {
 const arrayPerson = this.props.rowData;
 const index = _.findIndex(this.props.rowData, { id: id });
 if (arrayPerson.indexOf(id) > -1) {
   arrayPerson.splice(index, 1);
   this.setState({ rows: arrayPerson });
 }
```

can any one help me on this issue.

Comment: What issue you have got?

Comment: if i click on delete[x] its not getting deleted and there are few empty rows if i click on that index =0....  after clicking on empty  row and again if i click on data it shows  index as -1

Comment: Take a look at this [`link`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35901920/deleting-an-item-in-reactjs/35903300#35903300)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting an item in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35901920/deleting-an-item-in-reactjs)

Comment: @TheReason i have changed the code ,still its not working

Comment: You're getting the `arrayPerson` from component `props` when deleting, you should update this array in the parent component not in this component state.

Comment: can i get any example please

Comment: @Dyo i have already  done by using setState right..if i am not wrong.

Comment: You'll have to show your entire component and his parent so we'll know where `this.props.rowData` comes from and where to update it, also what you're rendering.

Comment: Added render code also

Comment: you're building the `<DynamicDataGrid>` with `this.props.rowData` but you're storing the modified table data in `this.state.rows`.

Comment: rows are nothing but rowData itself

Comment: that is not clear from the code you've provided.

Comment: rows={this.props.rowData}

Answer (score 1):

This is a working example for this what if different is that you are passing the data from parent to child for that u can do multiple thing.

The Parent Component.

```
class TestComp extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { listItems: [{ id: 1, text: "abc" }, { id: 2, text: "bcd" }, { id: 3, text: "dec" }] }
    this.handleRowClick = this.handleRowClick.bind(this);
}
handleRowClick(id) {

    const listItems = this.state.listItems;
    let copyListItems = [];
    listItems.forEach(function (item) {
        let objCopy = Object.assign({}, item);
        copyListItems.push(objCopy);
    });
    let updatedArray = _.remove(copyListItems, function (item) { return item.id == id; });

    this.setState({ listItems: copyListItems });
}
render() {

    return (
        <div>
            <ChildComp
                list={this.state.listItems}
                deleteHandler={this.handleRowClick}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

The Child Component that is receiving List items as props and when clicked the parent handler is being called which will update the List items and setState of Parent which will update the list being provided to child component hence it will be rendered.

```
export class ChildComp extends React.Component {

render() {
    let list = this.props.list.map((obj) =>
        <div key={obj.id} id={obj.id} style={{ padding: "10px", backgroundColor: "grey", border: "1px solid black" }} onClick={() => { this.props.deleteHandler(obj.id) }}> {obj.text} </div>
    );
    return (
        <div >
           {list}
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: no i have not used  this.state.rows......rows={this.props.rowData} these are only properties

Comment: you are setting the updated Rows in this.setState to rows.. now your 
this.state.rows contains the updated rows. u need to render them in order for the view to change otherwise , the render method will keep showing the output of original rows. also u should not mutate state or props

Comment: if we set "this.state .rows "in dataGrid it throws an error(TypeError: Cannot read property 'rowData' of null);

Comment: because you are receiving props from the parent. you need to set them in your state of your component because you are going to change them ..

Comment: sure i will give u a simple example ryt now

Comment: i have provided you with a working example for this .. if u want me to turn it into parent child combination which i presume you are using as the rowData is coming from a parent as props. i can update it too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164363/discussion-between-jmr-and-imran-qureshi).