# State not update while removing elements

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've code something like,

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        images: [],
    }
}

const tempImages = this.state.images;
tempImages.splice(index, 1);
this.setState({ images: tempImages });
```

were `index` will be dynamically come from table cell.

in the above code when I will try to remove the object from array it will not affect and not getting remove the element at that time after onwards state change it will set.

can someone please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting an item in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35901920/deleting-an-item-in-reactjs)

Comment: this is different @TheReason
my code is different from them

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it will be easier for someone to help you.

Comment: please provide full understanding code. bcoz in that case I don't know where are you using this and where its not getting update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lodash`

```
import _ from "lodash";

const tempImages = _.cloneDeep(this.state.images);
tempImages.splice(index, 1);
this.setState({ images: tempImages });
```

it will help you to clone your entire object from state and update at the moment.